# In Raphael.js, controlling order of elements on hover

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have the following code, and [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/Lpvk3agf/). I'm trying to get the topmost circle to go to the front when it's animated last, i.e. when the user goes over the mouseover areas starting from the bottom. In my head, this code should work due to the moboxonoff variable, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Edit for clarity: right now, the bottom circle is always on top of the top circle. I'd like this order to change depending on what order the circles' controlling mouseover areas are moused over.

```
xValues = [50, 50];
yValues = [100, 120];

var mouseoverStarts = [70, 90, 130],
    mouseoverEnds =  [90, 130, 150],
    mouseoverItems =  [[0], [0, 1], [1]];

var p0 = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);

var circles = []
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    circles[i] = p0.circle(xValues[i], yValues[i], 10);
    circles[i].attr({"fill": "#c00", stroke: "#888", "stroke-width":1.5});
    circles[i].id = "c"+i;
};

animate_on = function(num, ignoreindex, ignorearray) {
        if (moboxonoff[num] === 0) {
            p0.getById("c"+num).stop().animate({r: 30}, 480, "bounce");
            p0.getById("c"+num).toFront();
            moboxonoff[num] = 1
        };
};
animate_off = function(num, ignoreindex, ignorearray) {
        if (moboxonoff[num] == 1) {
            p0.getById("c"+num).stop().animate({r: 10}, 320, "bounce");
            moboxonoff[num] = 0
        };
};

moboxonoff = [];
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    moboxonoff[i] = 0;
};

debugopacity = 0.2; // set to 0 for final

moboxes = [];
for (i=0; i<mouseoverStarts.length; i++) {
    moboxes[i] = p0.rect(30, mouseoverStarts[i], 400, mouseoverEnds[i] - mouseoverStarts[i]);
    moboxes[i].attr({fill: "#00f", opacity: debugopacity});
    moboxes[i].id = "mob" + i;
    moboxes[i].hover(function () {
        j = parseInt(this.id.slice(3));
        mouseoverItems[j].forEach(animate_on);
        this.toFront();
        }, function () {
        mouseoverItems[j].forEach(animate_off);
        });
};
```

Comment: I would try and reduce the code further with more logging to isolate the bit of code causing the problem. Its quite fiddly to follow the flow of logic in the code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the middle rectangle to the last position in the first 3 arrays:

```
var mouseoverStarts = [70, 130, 90],
    mouseoverEnds =  [90, 150, 130],
    mouseoverItems =  [[0], [1], [0, 1]];
```

Remove the toFront() call on the animate functions

And just add a if condition in the mouseover function

```
if(j!=2){
  circles[j].toFront();
}
```

Also you can call the circles from the array directly, no need of creating another ID.

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/u2zL29jw/

Comment: Thank you; I think I can generalize this without hardcoding the 2 by checking if the length of mouseoverItems[j] == 1.